# Dart: Find memory leak using Observatory

Tags: dart

We are using Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Wed Dec 13 16:10:39 2017) on "linux_x64" and I've been using the observatory to find out how memory is allocated.

Under Allocation Profile -> Old Generation in observatory, I can see the following: 83.7MB of 498.5MB used

My questions are

1. I'm assuming 83.7MB is the memory used, but then what's the 498.5MB? Amount of memory allocated by the VM?
2. I can see the 498.5MB increasing over time even though the memory used is not that high. Why would the VM allocate more and more memory even though the app doesn't more than half?
3. When would Dart's VM release memory back to system? GC doesn't lower the allocated memory much.
4. How else could I narrow down where the potential memory leak is?

Thanks!